# R - Add SD regions as dashed lines to normal distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I have the following R script which produces the following image. I'd like to add SD regions to this normal curve (plus or minus 3 SD). In other words, two lines indicating the 68% region, and so on. You can see an example of the lines I'm talking about [here](http://www.forextrainingworldwide.com/wp-content/uploads/Standard_deviation_diagram.jpg).

```
g = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,8)
h<-hist(g, breaks=10, density=10, col="lightgray", xlab="Accuracy", main="Overall") 
xfit<-seq(min(g),max(g),length=40) 
yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(g),sd=sd(g)) 
yfit <- yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(g) 
lines(xfit, yfit, col="black", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: It will help if you supply example data (e.g. the values that make up `g`) so that this becomes a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [?segments](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/graphics/html/segments.html).  Try this:

```
x.vals <- c(mean(g)-(1:3*sd(g)), mean(g), mean(g)+(1:3*sd(g)))
y.vals <- dnorm(x.vals, mean=mean(g),sd=sd(g))*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(g)
segments(x0=x.vals, y0=0, x1=x.vals, y1=y.vals)
```

[image]

Note that not all SDs show up on the plot.  To make the original plot wider, you could use `xlim=c(-3,13)` in the call to `hist()` (and you'd also need to change the range of `xfit` accordingly).